# read() is blocked forever on raspberry pi 3 UART

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, uart

The C read() function frequently get blocked, especially if there is nothing connected on the Gpio pins (tx / rx), but I just hoped it would stop for itself when there is no conection, the same when there is wire conection but no data to read, but it just get blocked  until I force it to finish.

**Open**

```
fd = open("/dev/serial0", O_RDWR | O_NDELAY | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

**Read**

```
n = read( fd, value, 1 );
if (n < 0) {
printf ( "Error = %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
}
else if (n == 0) {
  printf ( "Read Nothing...\n");
}
```

**Set attribs**

```
int setAttr(int fd)
{
    //Read the configureation of the port 
    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr( fd, &options );

    //Set Baud Rate 
    cfsetispeed( &options, B9600 );
    cfsetospeed( &options, B9600 );

    //Setting other Port Stuff 
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; /*Make 8n1 */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;  /* No flow control */
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; /*READ doesn't block */
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; /* 0.1 seconds read timout */
    options.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; /* Turn on READ & ignore crtl lines */

    //Make raw
    cfmakeraw(&options);

    //Flush port, then applies attributes
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    return tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop when there is a connection but there's no data to read, either.

Comment: Actually since you opened it with O_NONBLOCK, it's supposed to return -1 and set errno to EAGAIN if there's nothing to read...

Answer (score 1):

For a UART port with nothing but tx/rx pins, there is no distinct "nothing connected" status. For the functionality you want, the port would need DCE/DTR pins and the `CLOCAL` flag (ignore modem control lines) would have to be removed from the termios settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the code below, after open() and it's not blocked anymore when tx/rx pins are not connected. Probably the port was going blocked after open().

```
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      /*
       * Could not open the port.
       */

      perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/serial0 - ");
    }
  else fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```